# Передать в метод класса весь генерируемый объект

Tags: javascript

Я пытался так:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(a) {
    this.name = 'wdadw';
    this.num = 2;
    this.a = a;
  }

  a() {
    console.log(Object.values(Object.values(Foo)));
  }
}

const b = new Foo('wd').a();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не понятно что вы хотите. Но так вы вернете
всё поля объекта

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(a) {
    this.name = 'wdadw';
    this.num = 2;
    this.a = a;
  }

  b() {
    console.log(Object.values(this));
  }
}

const b = new Foo('wd').b();
```